# python3-nmap host discovery no MAC address/hostname

Tags: python-3.x, networking, raspbian, nmap

I'm using the nmap3 python library to do nmap scans within python scripts, and put them in A JSON file. (https://pypi.org/project/python3-nmap/)

This works well, but the problem is that for some reason the hostname and MAC address discovery does not work.

nmap3 python (script execute as root):

```
network = nmap3.Nmap()
results = network.scan_top_ports("192.168.68.126", args="-sn")

with open(Network_discover, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(results, json_file, indent=4)*
```

Result (in JSON file):

```
{
    "192.168.68.126": {
        "osmatch": {},
        "ports": [],
        "hostname": [],   ///no hostname
        "macaddress": null,   ///macaddress "null"
        "state": {
            "state": "up",
            "reason": "arp-response",
            "reason_ttl": "0"
        }
    }
```

It is strange because hostname/MAC discovery does work in the nmap application for Linux, but also in the classic nmap library for python (has not been updated for 5 years now).

Example of the desired output:

```
sudo nmap -sn "192.168.68.126"
Starting Nmap ....................
Nmap scan report for 192.168.68.126
Host is up .........
**MAC Address: 01:23:34:67:89:00 (Synology Incorporated)**   //the line I'm talking about
Nmap done: ...........
```

I'm executing the python script as root, so permissions should not be a problem (and other root required tools like OS detection do work just fine).

UPDATE: It looks like the python3-nmap library has a bug in it's code. For some reason, the host discovery is not executed as root. I think I'm receiving the output from

```
nmap -sn "192.168.68.126"
```

While the output from

```
sudo nmap -sn "192.168.68.126"
```

is neccesary.

Still unable to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:
"**network.require_root(required=True)** before"
"results = network.scan_top_ports("192.168.68.126", args="-sn")"